# ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, alsa, libalsa

i am working on speech recognition . for this i am using "alsa-utils" but when i try to use this script

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo “Recording… Press Ctrl+C to Stop.”
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -q -f cd -t wav | ffmpeg -loglevel panic -y -i – -ar 16000 -acodec flac file.flac > /dev/null 2>&1

echo “Processing…”
wget -q -U “Mozilla/5.0” –post-file file.flac –header “Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000” -O – “http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?lang=en-us&client=chromium” | cut -d” -f12 >stt.txt

echo -n “You Said: ”
cat stt.txt

rm file.flac > /dev/null 2>&1
```

i am getting this error

```
    “Recording… Press Ctrl+C to Stop.”
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
“Processing…”
```

please help :(

Comment: Can you post the output of `arecord -l`?

Comment: hello @jamieguinan thanks for giving reply here is output of arecord -1

http://pastebin.com/1eyzKV4y

Comment: reply please i am waiting :(

Comment: Hey man, I had to have dinner. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the pastebin I see `card 0` then `device 0` or `device 1`, so try lining up the `arecord` command with `card,device` in that order like one of these,

```
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -q -f cd -t wav | ...
arecord -D plughw:0,1 -q -f cd -t wav | ...
```

Comment: you are really genius :) ok what i did is i put only first line 

`arecord -D plughw:0,0 -q -f cd -t wav | ...`

and one error gone . now only this error showing 

`arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory`

so i have two confusion 

one confusion is should i put both command which you replied in my script or only one ?? i did only one and its working should i add second one too or leave it as it is now.

second confusion about 

`arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory`

Comment: ok first one is working sir . so i am leaving it as it is but now i am facing only this error :(

`arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory`

Comment: So it no longer says "Invalid value for card", but still says "audio open error: No such file or directory?"

Comment: Try something like the command in this pastebin (which shows the first few bytes of the wave output generated) until you can get arecord working properly: http://pastebin.com/pwSBFBKw

Comment: i tried pastebin command and i got this 

`arecord: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy`

Comment: bdw i just removed -D from code and now second error also gone but i am not getting any sound output ? is this google api error or something causes i can see sound output file in folder but can't get response in terminal

Comment: If you remove `-D` it will simply record the default audio device to a file called `plughw:0,0`. What is the output of the command `fuser /dev/snd/pcm*` ?

Comment: sir should i remove -D or not ?? will it affect my code or i will face any error in future ??

and output of `fuser /dev/snd/pcm*`

`exepaul@ubuntu:~$ fuser /dev/snd/pcm*
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c:   25039m`

Comment: Keep the `-D`. And run `ps aux` or `gnome-system-monitor` and look for process 25039, which is holding your device and causing the `Device or resource busy`.

Comment: sir i got this result of `ps aux' command 

`exepaul  25039  9.7  2.8 550872 28828 ?        S<l  13:27  15:06 /usr/bin/pulsea`

Comment: Ok, `pulseaudio` is managing your audio device, which it will do if you have a browser open. Try closing any apps that might be producing audio, including your web browser, and `pulseaudio` should release the device so that `arecord` can use it directly.

Comment: Also try removing the `-D` option _and also the device name_, like this: `arecord -q -f cd -t wav`, which should use arecord through pulseaudio. I don't have much experience with pulseaudio, but this is my best guess. Good luck to you.