# Error "Invalid value for card" with mic in my Node script

Tags: node.js, microphone, alsa

I'm trying to build a little Node script to listen to the microphone and then send the audio to a server and I'm stuck with the `mic` package.

I get this error:

```
Received Info: ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1713:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
arecord: main:788: 
Received Info: erreur à l'ouverture audio: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

I have tried to run `arecord -d 5 -f U8 sample.mp3` on my machine (Linux) and it works well (I can then listen to what I said with `aplay sample.mp3`).

I have seen [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398435/alsa-lib-pcm-hw-c1667-snd-pcm-hw-open-invalid-value-for-card-arecord-main7) but don't really understand how this applies to my case. In case you need, this is the output of `arecord -l`

```
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels CAPTURE ****
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 0/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

And this is the options object I pass to `mic`

```
"MIC_CONFIG": {
        "rate": 8000,
        "channels": 1,
        "debug": true,
        "exitOnSilence": 6
    }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: doesn't really solve the problem but it worked with `node-record-lpcm16` instead of `mic` (using `rec` as `recordProgram` in the config)